# How to include my own rule base (.pl) while launching json_prolog

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to include my rule base written in a prolog file(.pl) and launch it through the json_prolog launch file suggested in [json_prolog launch](http://www.knowrob.org/doc/interact_with_knowrob_via_ros). How can I do it? I can load the prolog file from a python node by querying ['CHOPIN.pl']. But when I do the same in json_prolog launch file, the query returns error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rohit/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/knowrob_CHOPIN/scripts/tutorial_test_query.py", line 16, in 
query = prolog.query("hot(location1).")
File "/home/rohit/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/json_prolog/prolog.py", line 69, in query
return PrologQuery(query_str)
File "/home/rohit/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/json_prolog/prolog.py", line 22, in **init**
raise PrologException('Prolog query failed: %s' % result.message)
json_prolog.prolog.PrologException: "Prolog query failed: PrologException: error(syntax_error(operator_expected), string('expand_goal((hot(location1).),_Q), call(_Q) . ', 27))"

This is a specific error for my query. But, I hope you get the idea.

So, how do I load my rule base file(rule_base.pl) while launching json_prolog, to make it global and to be queried directly?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195388/how-to-include-my-own-rule-base-(.pl)-while-launching-json_prolog/) by [olchandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20525/olchandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The json_prolog node reads two ROS parameters, the initial package to be loaded and an initialization goal, see [here](https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob/blob/master/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/JSONPrologNode.java#L285), which you can use to pass the 'consult' or 'use_module' directive. Alternatively, as you have created your own package, you can give that package as initial_package argument when starting json_prolog, which will then load everything that is listed in your init.pl. You can have a look at other KnowRob packages for examples.

The error you list above was however caused by a syntax error: When sending commands via json_prolog, do not add the trailing dot '.'. All commands are passed via the 'expand_goal' predicate, so they should not have the '.' inside which indicates the end of a query.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [olchandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20525/olchandra/) on 2014-10-21**:
Hello again. Thanks to your answer I can load the prolog file while starting json_prolog, by giving the package name as argument. But still I cannot pass the prolog file as the parameter "initial_package" in the [launch file for json_prolog](http://www.knowrob.org/doc/interact_with_knowrob_via_ros).

**Comment by [olchandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/20525/olchandra/) on 2014-10-21**:
Ok...I got to load the prolog file from json_prolog launch file. I think the launch file suggested [here](http://www.knowrob.org/doc/interact_with_knowrob_via_ros) is not accurate. It works only when I put the param inside node. Thank you again moritz.